# Streaming movies via network stops after a few secs but only on WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming, wifi-transfer

Streaming movies via network stops after a few secs but only on Wifi? (XP HOME SP3)

I have 2 computers, 1 Main tower PC (with ext 2 TB drive), and a 3GB laptop.  When I stream movies from my 2TB ext drive (via network), connected to the main PC, everything is good when the laptop is  connected via Ethernet cable, but when it's unplugged and using WiFi, the stream stops after 2-3 seconds.  When the stream stops, it also disconnects from the WiFi.

I can still get all other files and even stream MP3 music from the ext drive using wifi,
but not any movies in any format via WiFi. it's fine when connected using Ethernet cable.
My sister's laptop streams movies from my network very well on WiFi when she visits.

Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by " 3gb laptop" ? 
as the problem occurs only on WIFI, that might be bandwidth related. maybe your sister's laptop uses Wireless N 300/600 or even higher transfer speeds but your WIFI adapter only supports G. and you said that "when the stream stops it also disconnects from the wi-fi " but you also said that you can still get all other files on WIFI!

Comment: What video players have you tried?